# D3: Having trouble selecting a path from json data

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, path

I'm having trouble assigning an id to the paths from an external `json` file of coordinates, despite reading numerous questions and answers that others have posted on the matter. The data in the file looks like this (it's also referenced in the header of my html, see below):

```
var neighborhoods_json = {
"type": "FeatureCollection",                                                                                
"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "Name": "Roslindale", "density": 5.5800 }, "geometry": { "type": "MultiPolygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ [ -71.1259, 42.2720 ], [ -71.1257, 42.2723 ], [ -71.1256, 42.2724 ], [ -71.1255, 42.2725 ],....
```

I've seen other people ask this same question, and the answer was the add this line to create the id for each path:

```
 .attr("id", function(d) {return d.id;})
```

but my `json` data doesn't contain an `id`, so I thought I'd use the `Name` instead:

```
 .attr("id", function(d) {return d.Name;})
```

I then tried to select one of the paths created, using `Name` as `id`. The idea was to simply select one of the paths, and then change the color of its fill to red. But I'm either not assigning the ids correctly, or not selecting the path correctly. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maptimeboston.github.io/d3-maptime/example3/neighborhoods.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        var width = 700,
            height = 580;

        var svg = d3.select( "body" )
          .append( "svg" )
          .attr( "width", width )
          .attr( "height", height );

        var neighborhoods = svg.append( "g" );

        var albersProjection = d3.geo.albers()
          .scale( 190000 )
          .rotate( [71.057,0] )
          .center( [0, 42.313] )
          .translate( [width/2,height/2] );

        var geoPath = d3.geo.path()
          .projection( albersProjection );

        neighborhoods.selectAll( "path" )
          .data( neighborhoods_json.features )
          .enter()
          .append("path")
            .attr( "d", geoPath)
            .attr("id", function(d) {return d.Name;})
            .attr("fill", "steelblue");

        neighborhoods.select("path#Roslindale")
            .attr("fill", "red");

    </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In you `id` function the `Name` property is nested inside a `properties` property

```
neighborhoods.selectAll( "path" )
          .data( neighborhoods_json.features )
          .enter()
          .append("path")
            .attr( "d", geoPath)
            .attr("id", function(d) {return d.properties.Name;})
            .attr("fill", "steelblue");
```

[Working jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q4m3uus0/)